# Prove or disprove the claim: $\ker(T^{n}) = \ker(T^{n+1})$ for infinite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T:V \rightarrow V$, if $V$ is infinite dimensional, can one still claim that $\ker(T^{n}) = \ker(T^{n+1})$ for some $n \geq 1$? If yes prove it, if not provide a counter example.

I feel that the answer is No, as intuitively I feel that the Kernel/Nullspace can "expand" infinitely and does not necessarily reached a "stable" state, but I cant find a counter example for this.

Hence if I'm right, could anyone give me the needed counter-example to illustrate this? If I'm wrong, how do I then prove this claim ?

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated.

Comment: may be you should first give some examples of infinite dimensional spaces and some linear maps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right.

Consider the infinite-dimensional space of eventually zero real sequences: $V = \bigoplus\limits_{\infty} \mathbb{R}$. Define $T(a) = b$ to be a sequence obtained by shifting everything to the left: $b_{n} = a_{n+1}$, so that $a = (a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots)$ maps to $b = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots)$.

Now $\ker(T^n)$ is $n$-dimensional and consists of all sequences whose only non-zero terms are the first $n$ terms.

Comment: Well, in a way *all* examples for this are basically the same (for varying degrees of "basically")

Answer (score 6):

*Hint:* Let $T$ be derivation in the space of polynomials.